# How to build Mono Application on linux

Tags: linux, mono

I have 2 .cs files and a .dll file. i would like to build an run it on Debian Linux. 
Were can i find a good tutorial on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Mono
2. At terminal use `mcs` to compile your source files, just like what you do on Windows with csc, http://linux.die.net/man/1/mcs

Another option is to install MonoDevelop and create a new project with your files.

Comment: Thnx for the respons. I need to run the application on a raspberry pi and would really like to compile and run the program with the terminal. I have a file called Main.cs and MplayerControl.cs and a LibMplayer.dll

Comment: Raspberry Pi is not the general "Debian Linux", so you should make it very clear when you asked the question. So far, there is public information on whether Mono itself (the runtime) can be installed/used on such a device, so discussing how to compile a Mono application and run it is kind of meaningless.